# Exception in hibernate in JDBC

Tags: java, database, oracle, hibernate, jdbc

I am running hibernate program in eclipse and try to connect with database.i added all the required jars.but it is throwing

**exceptionorg.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException**

Here is my code:

**Employee.java**

```
public class Employee {  
private int id;  
private String firstName,lastName;  

public int getId() {  
    return id;  
}  
public void setId(int id) {  
    this.id = id;  
}  
public String getFirstName() {  
    return firstName;  
}  
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {  
    this.firstName = firstName;  
}  
public String getLastName() {  
    return lastName;  
}  
public void setLastName(String lastName) {  
    this.lastName = lastName;  
}  


}
```

**Employee.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC  
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"  
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">  

 <hibernate-mapping>  
  <class name="com.acnovate.Employee" table="emp1000">  
    <id name="id">  
     <generator class="assigned"></generator>  
    </id>  

    <property name="firstName" column="firstname"></property>  
    <property name="lastName" column="lastname"></property>  

  </class>  

 </hibernate-mapping>
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC  
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"  
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">  

<hibernate-configuration>  

    <session-factory>  
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>  
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</property>  
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl</property>  
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">system</property>  
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">Manager7</property>  
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>  
    <mapping resource="Employee.hbm.xml"/>  
    </session-factory>  

</hibernate-configuration>
```

**StoreData.java**

```
import org.hibernate.Session;  
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;  
import org.hibernate.Transaction;  
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;  

public class StoreData {  
public static void main(String[] args) {  

    //creating configuration object  
    Configuration cfg=new Configuration();  
    cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");//populates the data of the configuration file  

    //creating session factory object  
    SessionFactory factory=cfg.buildSessionFactory();  

    //creating session object  
    Session session=factory.openSession();  

    //creating transaction object  
    Transaction t=session.beginTransaction();  

    Employee e1=new Employee();  
    e1.setId(115);  
    e1.setFirstName("sonoo");  
    e1.setLastName("jaiswal");  

    session.persist(e1);//persisting the object  

    t.commit();//transaction is committed  
    session.close();  

    System.out.println("successfully saved");  

}  
}
```

**and i am facing the following exception.**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:29)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:420)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1326)
    at com.acnovate.StoreData.main(StoreData.java:22)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
localhost:1521:orcl

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:261)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:414)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:417)
    ... 5 more
```

I checked my code but didn't find any issue.please help me to getting out of this errors.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The error says that `localhost:1521:orcl` is not there, have you checked that the connection is correct? Also check whether the port is not being blocked by a firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check this

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl
```

Oracle doesn't recognize `orcl` SID.

Comment: i tired jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl and jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe, but it didn't work.

Comment: @JayeshVyas You need to check SID